# How to scare the pigeons?

Tags: once-upon-a-tower

How do you scare 5 pigeons? I don't understand.

I've been trying to "scare" them but i just end up killing them;
please help :(

Comment: This would be a stronger question if it included why you want to scare the pigeons.  Knowing nothing about this game, my guess is that there is an achievement or quest involved.

Answer (score 1):

pigeons are the birds outside the tower wall. You just have to hit a wall besides them and they fly away "scared"